# Recursive Python Function to print all combination of letters which selected numbers from numpad

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to get all combination of letter which selected numbers from numpad. For example;

If I press 2(abc) and 3(def) then ad,ae,af,bd,be,bf,cd,ce,cf,abd,abe,........ all combination.

I am trying to make it with recursive function but I stucked and I take this error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Can any one help me ?

```
A = {
 '2':['A','B','C'],
 '3':['D','E','F'],
 '4':['G','H','I'],
 '5':['J','K','L'],
 '6':['M','N','O'],
 '7':['P','Q','R','S'],
 '8':['T','U','V'],
 '9':['W','X','Y','Z']
}

def combination(numbers,data,strout = ''):
    x = len(numbers)
    print(x)
    if x >= 1:
        for i in range(x):
            y = numbers[i:i+1]
            for k in len(data[y]):
                combination(numbers[i:i+1], data,strout = strout+(data[y][k],))
    else:
        return '0'


combination('235', A,'')
```

Comment: For what you concatenate string and tuple in `strout+(data[y][k],)`? It's impossible operation. And the line `for k in len(data[y])` is invalid, because `len` returns integer, not iterable, as error you get says. You need to debug your algorithm.

Comment: The problem is here: `for k in len(data[y]):`. `data[y]` is a list of strings, but you do `len` of that, which is an int. You can't `for k in int`.

Comment: No need to write `numbers[i:i+1]`. `numbers[i]` much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and the [unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) is a possible way to go:

```py
from itertools import product

def combination(numbers, data):
    letters = product(*[''.join(data[number]) for number in numbers])
    return ','.join(''.join(item).lower() for item in letters)
```

Demo:

```py
In [184]: A = {'2': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     ...:      '3': ['D', 'E', 'F'],
     ...:      '4': ['G', 'H', 'I'],
     ...:      '5': ['J', 'K', 'L'],
     ...:      '6': ['M', 'N', 'O'],
     ...:      '7': ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'],
     ...:      '8': ['T', 'U', 'V'],
     ...:      '9': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']}
     ...: 

In [185]: combination('', A)
Out[185]: ''

In [186]: combination('2', A)
Out[186]: 'a,b,c'

In [187]: combination('23', A)
Out[187]: 'ad,ae,af,bd,be,bf,cd,ce,cf'

In [188]: combination('235', A)
Out[188]: 'adj,adk,adl,aej,aek,ael,afj,afk,afl,bdj,bdk,bdl,bej,bek,bel,bfj,bfk,bfl,cdj,cdk,cdl,cej,cek,cel,cfj,cfk,cfl'
```

---

**EDIT**

As per your request, I'm attaching two further solutions that do not rely on the `itertools` module:

```py
def it_combination(numbers, data):
    '''Iterative cartesian product'''
    values = [data[key] for key in numbers]
    result = [[]]
    for letters in values:
        result = [lst + [letter] for lst in result for letter in letters]
    return ','.join(''.join(seq).lower() for seq in result)

def rec_combination(numbers, data):
    '''Recursive cartesian product'''

    def wrapped(numbers, data, result=[[]]):
        if not numbers:
            return result
        else:
            letters = data[numbers[0]]
            result = [lst + [letter] for lst in result for letter in letters]
            return wrapped(numbers[1:], data, result)

    return ','.join(''.join(seq).lower() for seq in wrapped(numbers, data))
```

Sample run:

```py
In [190]: combination('', A) == it_combination('', A) == rec_combination('', A)
Out[190]: True

In [191]: combination('2', A) == it_combination('2', A) == rec_combination('2', A)
Out[191]: True

In [192]: combination('23', A) == it_combination('23', A) == rec_combination('23', A)
Out[192]: True

In [193]: combination('235', A) == it_combination('235', A) == rec_combination('235', A)
Out[193]: True
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working. How ever I am trying to find solution without any importing class, but thank you again.

Comment: My pleasure. I edited my answer to provide you with two further solutions that do not rely on `itertools`.